# Drupal hook_submit write to db

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am now taking on the challenge of building a custom module.

I have started really small just to try and the understanding of drupal hooks and modules.

I have created a simple form with one text entry, the only validation is that the field is not empty.

On the form submit I would like to write to a custom table. The table exists.
My fields are:
nid int(11)
eid int(11) Primary Key Auto Increment
title varchar(50)

Here is my form:

```
function my_module_my_form($form_state) {
$form['esp'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Add a ESP'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => FALSE,

);
$form['esp']['title'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('ESP Name'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => '',
  '#description' => "Enter the ESP Name",
  '#size' => 20,
  '#maxlength' => 20,
);

$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Submit'),
);
return $form;
 }
```

and here is the `hook_submit()` that I have setup:

```
function my_module_my_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
db_query("INSERT INTO my_module_esp (title) VALUES (".$form_state['values']['title'].")");
drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
}
```

But this does not work... any suggestions?
Also I would like the add the latest nid to this table, how would I get that value and update it in the db so it does not affect any other modules?

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the form's hierarchy into account.  Try using:

```
function my_module_my_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  db_query('INSERT INTO {my_module_esp} (title) VALUES ("%s")', $form_state['values']['esp']['title']);
  drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
}
```

If you need to to assign this a nid, then you should actually create a node in your code so that 301 is *really* associated with something.  The primary key in the node table is auto_increment, so if you don't create a node in this code, then someone else could go create a blog post and would get assigned 301.  Use [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6) to create a node

Comment: lets say the last node entered was 300, then I want to assign this to be node 301 and let drupal know that it is now at count 301 and will not assign 301 to anything else as a nid.

Comment: I did a print_r on my $form_state and my input appears under
`$form_state['values']['title'];`
So I used the db query as follows:
`db_query('INSERT INTO {my_module_api_esp} (title) VALUES ("%s")', $form_state['values']['title']);`
but I am still not seeing this being inserted into my db :( I never thought this could be so frustrating. Thank you for your advice, is there anything else I could try or should maybe know in order to make this work?

Comment: Is the Drupal message being set at least, telling you the form was submitted?

Comment: Hi Laxman, well its a bit weird. I am now able to write to the database, however the drupal message doesn't show.

However I am not too worrie about this at the moment.
I have looked all around drupal for a guide on building the .module, and how to build this as a node type.

I was wondering if maybe you could help guide me or direct me to something that I haven't seen

Comment: That is really grounds for a separate question, though I know there are at least a few questions about creating a node type in a module. I recommend searching around here and Google for creating a content type in a module